# Objective C @autoreleasepool infinite loop taking screenshots

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, screenshot, autorelease

I have a memory issue with small app taking infinite amount of screenshots every X milliseconds and displaying them in a imageview. Even with autorelease, it floods the memory very quickly. Here's the code:

```
- (void)draw {
    do {
        @autoreleasepool {
            CGImageRef image1 = CGDisplayCreateImage(kCGDirectMainDisplay);

            NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image1];
            NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] init];
            [image addRepresentation:bitmapRep];
            _imageView.image = image;
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }
    }while(true);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use @autoreleasepool without ARC.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Yes you can. It was introduced at the same time as ARC, but does not require ARC.

Comment: Since you're never returning control to a runloop, I'm assuming this is being run on a background thread. You're accessing a UI control (`_imageView`), which is only allowed on the main thread. You should probably change that to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_thread(), ^{ _imageView.image = image; });`

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the original post, but yes, I do use ARC, and yes, this loop is running in its own thread. But thanks guys, explicitly releasing image with CGImageRelease(image1); did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to release the image using `CGImageRelease`

```
- (void)draw {
    do {
        @autoreleasepool {
            CGImageRef image1 = CGDisplayCreateImage(kCGDirectMainDisplay);

            NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image1];
            NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] init];
            [image addRepresentation:bitmapRep];
            _imageView.image = image;
            CGImageRelease(image1);   // release the image
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }
    }
    while(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did it. I thought ARC was taking care of releasing that image.

Comment: ARC was taking care of releasing ObjC objects, like `NSImage` and `NSBitmapImageRep`. But `CGImageRef` is a core foundation object (just a pointer to a C structure) which ARC cannot handle for you

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're not using ARC here.

You seem to have misunderstood what an autorelease pool does. It doesn't magically release objects by its own prerogative (that's what ARC is for!). You add objects to the pool — either by using `autorelease` (in managed retain/release mode) or by using a convenience constructor that autoreleases for you — and when it's destroyed, the pool will release each object once for every time that objet was added to the pool. The method you are using to create the objects here, `alloc`, returns an object that you own, so you must explicitly release your ownership the object.

Just add to the bottom of your loop:

```
[image release];
[bitmapRep release];
CGImageRelease(image1);
```